# Back-end optimization for angular-django application

Tags: django, angularjs, optimization

My development stack is angular -> django rest framework -> django. I am developing a website which is not a single page application. I have different angular app for different pages with shared components and services. With factors like browser caching in mind, when a page is requested which is a better model:

1. Compute data on backend first with available information and use angular on the client to take care of further actions on the page like voting/commenting etc.
2. Load only template from backend and let angular populate it with content.

Please let me know if my approach is altogether wrong.

Comment: both. compute data on backend as much as you can and populate it with angularjs.

Comment: The part I want to know is in case i use purely angular to get data, will the html template be along with other static data cached?